# Do aerobatics pilots do more to account for turbulence in their flying than passenger plane pilots?

Tags: aerobatics, turbulence

Non-aviator here. I was trying to make a comparison when talking to a friend earlier about how when you're trying to do something complicated and delicate, you have to do more to account for environmental factors that are out of your control.

I made the analogy of a passenger plane pilot that can just kind of "push through" most turbulence as opposed to an aerobatics pilot who has to "play the wind" more, accounting for the turbulence instead of just barreling through. It occurred to me, though, that I don't know whether this is actually true. Is my aviation analogy incorrect, and if so, is there a way to make it better?

Comment: Best way to make it better is to listen to the guy on the route in front of you and if he says "moderate turbulence", ask for a deviation.

Comment: Your analogy doesn't have any real basis to it.  I.e. why couldn't an aerobatic pilot just "push through" turbulence and a passenger plane pilot "play the wind"?  They are definitely different, but your comparison doesn't help us understand the root of your confusion...

Comment: If you are flying a faster aircraft, your difference between stall Vs and manoeuvring speed Va is correspondingly larger, so you can dare push through stronger turbulence. And if you are flying a larger aircraft, the larger moment of inertia means the pitching and banking is slower, though so is your control response. But the technique is still the same, just different points where you decide the turbulence is too strong and you need to fly around the weather.